# Is App Script Execution API Load Balanced?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently using App Script Execution API to edit and retrieve spreadsheet data, and I'm curious on how about how much server load a single execution API can handle.

How does app scripts deal with multiple requests from many users to a single deployed Execution API? Is there built in load balancing? Does it make sense to deploy multiple identical scripts, and spread the load?

Answer (score 0):

Looked around the community and googled for sometime, but I can't find a doc that focuses about it. There's no definitive doc that discusses/states/mentions anything about the *max server load* and *load balancing* of the Execution API. What you would always end up finding when lurking around, are the [API Limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#limitations) and the [Current Quotas and Limitations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas). These, I think, are pretty much the best guide you can find, if you are trying to know what NOT to do.